# Removing z-dimension while writing shapefile using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

There is such a code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsFeature, QgsField, QgsFields,
QgsGeometry, QgsPoint, QgsVectorFileWriter)
from qgis.utils import QGis, iface
iface.legendInterface().layers()
sluoksniu_saras=iface.legendInterface().layers()
for cL in sluoksniu_saras:
    fn='D:\\Ko\\'+cL.name()
    ret = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(cL, fn, "Windows-1257",\
    QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(cL.crs()), driverName="ESRI Shapefile",\
    forceMulti =False, includeZ = False)
    if ret == QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
       print "Irasyta i " +fn + " !"
print 'viskas'
```

In theory, he should write all open layers of the project in a specific folder and reset the z-dimension. Layers are recorded, but the z-dimension is not reset. Where is the mistake? I'm using QGIS 2.16

Answer (score 1):

It's mentioned in the [API for QGIS 2.16](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#abb1879ababb5d662ff95d7374d742008) that you need to set the `overrideGeometryType` parameter:

> **includeZ** - set to true to include z dimension in output. This option is only valid if overrideGeometryType is set.

Try including this parameter in your code.

---

**Edit:**

In response to your comment, you could try something like the following where I assumed you used a point shapefile for the geometry but you can [check here](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsWkbTypes.html#a70dff7aceefd4b16909f038e32aece11ab4b00cf5f667f3c8164d955613c93dfa) for other geometry types:

```py
ret = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(cL, fn, "Windows-1257",\
    QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(cL.crs()), driverName="ESRI Shapefile",\
    forceMulti =False, overrideGeometryType=QgsWKBTypes.PointZ, includeZ=False)
```

(*Note: I no longer have QGIS 2.16 installed as it is quite old now so cannot test this. You should perhaps consider updating to the latest version*)

Comment: all this is certainly wonderful, but I have 0 days experience with Python. I downloaded this code from the Internet, just added the missing and thought that it would work. It does not work. Would it not make it difficult for you to indicate how I should do this? Thanks.

Comment: @Smaigas - See the edited post.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Now my code is working. Below I will lay out the working code.
P.S. I can not install a newer version, the latest version is 2.16, which works on Windows XP

Comment: @Smaigas - Most welcome, glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsFeature, QgsField, QgsFields,
QgsGeometry, QgsPoint, QgsVectorFileWriter)
from qgis.utils import QGis, iface
#iface.legendInterface().layers()
sluoksniu_saras=iface.legendInterface().layers()
for cL in sluoksniu_saras:
    fn='D:\\Ko\\'+cL.name()
    geom_name = {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}
    geom_type = cL.geometryType()
    tipas=geom_name[geom_type]
    ret = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(cL, fn, "Windows-1257",\
    QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(cL.crs()), driverName="ESRI Shapefile",\
    overrideGeometryType=tipas, forceMulti = False, includeZ = False)
    if ret == QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
       print "Irasyta i " +fn + " !"
print 'viskas'
```

Thanks for the help. (Ačiū už pagalbą)